# How can I get more than the last 15 Tweets?

Tags: node.js, npm, tweets

I'm using Twitter npm package for node and when I query I just get 15 tweets max. How can I access more results? Here is my code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
      client.get('search/tweets', {q: hashTags}, function(error, tweets, response) {
        if (!error) {
          var size = Object.keys(tweets.statuses).length;
          //var size = tweets.search_metadata.count;
          console.log(tweets.search_metadata.count);
          for(var i = 0; i<size; i++){
              res.write(
                "<div style='font-family: Arial; border: dashed 1px #ebd2ee; padding: 12px; margin:4px;'>" +
                  "<p style='font-size:20px; text-transform: UPPERCASE;'>" + tweets.statuses[i].user.name + "</p>" +
                  "<p style='font-size:14px;'>" + tweets.statuses[i].text + "</p>" +
                  "<br /><span style='font-size:14px; color:#A9A9A9;'>" + tweets.statuses[i].created_at + "</span></div>");
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Read their document here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets. They have option count which has default is 15 and maximum is 100. I think it is what you need

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/Pomax/Twitter-Personal-Feed-Curator/blob/master/routes.js#L14-L34 paired with https://github.com/Pomax/Twitter-Personal-Feed-Curator/blob/master/public/letsdothis.js#L115+L129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the count parameter. From the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets):

> **count**  (optional)
>
> The number of tweets to return per page, up to a maximum of 100. Defaults to 15. This was formerly the “rpp” parameter in the old Search API.